# Executing an "m of n" transaction reverts

Tags: gnosis-safe

On our network, basically a lightly customized safe-react on top of a Rinkeby-like AuRA network. Nethermind eth clients.

When an m of n transaction is finally approved by quorum, the transaction needs to be "Executed". This is done by sending a contract call to the safe address.

The user interface first displays a warning "this transaction will likely fail". Underneath it has sent a trial call
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_call", "params": [{"from": "0x797F9999283471393D6497FAfc020F0F80870Be7", "to": "0x797F9999283471393D6497FAfc020
F0F80870Be7", "data": "0xc4ca3a9c000000000000000000000000797f9999283471393d6497fafc020f0f80870be700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}, "latest"], "id
": 1}

This fails with a revert.  797f is the address of the safe; the transaction is being sent by 190defi as seen below.

Pushing through a signed request anyway produces this transaction log:
http://bx.testnet.shyft.network/tx/0x0789d43f218fbe1b9c79b6b9382fd0025a0f2a2708e0b0af3f973cd778ff1bff/internal-transactions

I see in the logs this does delegateCall to my copy of GnosisSafe
http://bx.testnet.shyft.network/address/0xd9Db270c1B5E3Bd161E8c8503c55cEABeE709552/transactions

How can I understand better why this is reverting?

https://rpc.testnet.shyft.network/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Someone suggested a problem with transaction gas. I 100x'ed the gas estimation and price.  The transaction went through and successfully executed:
https://bx.testnet.shyft.network/tx/0xca5d6c7369ed98d2fed86f9260289a47bdc3ed0ba2ee44f1bdad211115b9b4c5/internal-transactions

it used less than it had originally proposed.

Now the transaction gateway does not reflect the change in transaction status.